# using Eclipse 4 css dependencies for a simple swt application

Tags: java, css, eclipse, swt, e4

I want to use css jar dependencies of eclipse e4 in my SWT Application (not RCP Application), how can i do it ? can any one guide me ?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, the Eclipse CSS plugins have dependencies on other Eclipse plugins so they will not work outside of an Eclipse RCP.

Comment: but if we put all the eclipse css plugins on the class path, it should work, but how can i instantiate and use the appropriate Class of the eclipse css plugins to change the look and feel of an SWT components ?

Comment: No, the Eclipse plugins need to be started correctly by the Eclipse initialization code. In any case the CSS plugins rely heavily on the Eclipse extension point mechanism to define how objects are handled.